# iOS - Playing video through UIWebView: Player controls appear in awkward position

Tags: ios, uiwebview, video-streaming

I'm trying to play a .m3u8 through a webView inside a HTML video tag.

The video plays correctly and has the functionality I need. But the presentation is off... The player controls appear on the bottom of the video, overlayed half-way on and half-way off the video content.

(Sorry, massive screenshots)
[image: Screenshot of problem]

Here, I extended the frame for the webview, and you can see that the video stops, but the controls appear lower.
[image: Extended webview frame]

Does anyone know if there is a way to reposition the player's controls?

Here's my webview code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    _webView.delegate = self;
    _webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.pulpwoodpress.com/playVidTest.html";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    _webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView
{

    NSLog(@"%f, %f", theWebView.scrollView.contentSize.width, theWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height);

    CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(theWebView.scrollView.contentSize.width, theWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
    CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;

    float rw = viewSize.width / contentSize.width;

    theWebView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = rw;
    theWebView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = rw;
    theWebView.scrollView.zoomScale = rw;

    theWebView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 17);
}
```